# Crear una variable de un comando extenso en Powershell

Tags: powershell

Tengo un problema con un script que estoy montando para gestionar versiones de software básico que podemos tener todos instalados en los equipos, el caso es que he encontrado el siguiente comando para que me muestre por pantalla las versiones de los programas que tengo instalado en mi equipo:

Por ejemplo Google Chrome:

```
gp HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | ? {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.DisplayName) } | select DisplayName , version| Where {$_.DisplayName -like "Google Chrome*"}
```

Este comando me muestra lo siguiente:

```
DisplayName  
-----------  
Google Chrome
```

El problema viene de que no soy capaz de redirigir correctamente la salida de ese comando a un fichero, entiendo que si pudiera asignarlo a una variable podría, pero no soy capaz de asignar ese pedazo de comando a una variable, siempre me da error, he probado de mil maneras pero me es imposible.

A ver si alguien puede echarme un cable!
Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: puedes porfavor colocar el codigo de algunos de los intentos que haz hecho?

Comment: al final del codigo simplemente agrega una redireccion a archivo con `>` para crear y sobrescribir y  `>>` para crear o anexar al contenido existente ejemplo: `dir >> resultado.txt` ejecutara el comando dir y enviara su salida al archivo resultado.txt

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar al final del comando Out-File -FilePath . Algo asi como esto:

```
 $hklm='HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
 $hklmwow="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"
 
 gp $hklm, $hklmwow | 
     ? {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.DisplayName) } |
     select DisplayName, version | 
     Where {$_.DisplayName -like "Google Chrome*"} |  
     Out-File -FilePath gp.txt
```